# Change color of siblings when child is hovered combined with nth-child

Tags: css, css-selectors

I'm trying to find out if it's possible to change the color of my whole `<ul>` list when an `<li>` is hovered.

The caveat is that I want each `<li>` child to change the `<ul>` a different color. For example, the first li hovered will change itself and all its siblings red, the second li hovered will change itself and siblings blue, etc. I can get all the siblings to change color when a single `<li>` is hovered, but I can't seem to make it work with `nth-child`.

Edit: I did read through [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1014861/is-there-a-css-parent-selector) but I'm not seeing specifically how it can be combined with nth-child.

Here is the code that I'm working with so far:

```
    /*when child is hovered, parent will change to this color*/
    ul:hover > li a {
    color: var(--apricot); 
    }
    
    /*when child is hovered, child will change to this color*/
       ul:hover li:nth-child(1) a:hover { 
         color: var(--apricot) !important; 
       }
```

Is there any way to make this work so that the siblings will change a different color depending on what child is hovered?

Comment: ul:nth-of-type(1) li a:hover {}

Answer (score 3):

You may use the [`:has()` pseudo class](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:has) to achieve it, but it worth noting that [some old browsers and Firefox](https://caniuse.com/?search=%3Ahas()) might not work.

```css
ul:has(li:nth-child(1):hover) {
  color: red;
}

ul:has(li:nth-child(2):hover) {
  color: blue;
}

ul:has(li:nth-child(3):hover) {
  color: green;
}

ul:has(li:nth-child(4):hover) {
  color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>item 1</li>
  <li>item 2</li>
  <li>item 3</li>
  <li>item 4</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: It's worth noting that `:has()` is experimental and probably shouldn't be used in production yet in _any_ browser. That being said, it would be greeeat if Firefox would get a move on and prioritize support for it.

Comment: Thank you! Wow, didn't know about the :has selector. However, if my <li> contains an <a> child, can this still work?